# Delayed chained payment PayPal fee documentation issue

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I'm using Delayed Chained Payment in this project: https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-dotnet in sandbox environment.

When I use default fee settings (*feesPayer.field = null*) fees work according to documentation https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/ scenario "**Each Receiver Pays the Fee in a Chained Payment**". This works all right. However, when I set *feesPayer.field = "PRIMARYRECEIVER"* it should work accoring to scenario "**Primary Receiver Pays the Fee in a Chained Payment**" from the same documentation, but it does not match.

My use case: normal user sends the payment and 1st fee is paid by primary receiver like in documentation. However, when I call ExecutePayment request to send payment to a secondary receiver, 2nd fee does not occur like in documentation.

I should be paying both fees, but the 2nd fee does not exist - where is the issue? Is the documentation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "second fee" if you have the primary receiver paying the whole fee.  When the primary receivers the initial payment they pay the entire fee right then, so when you release secondary funds, that fee has already been paid.  You won't see it again (in that case PayPal would be double dipping, which they don't do).

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. I got confused about the additional 0.3$ fee in second transaction.